# DropDownList resets to the first item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two bound to objectdatasource dropdownlists.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgram" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProgramsDS" 
     DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="True" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProgram_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ProgramsDS" runat="server" 
     OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
     TypeName="WebAdminTools.DATA.DSTableAdapters.ProgramTA" 
     UpdateMethod="Update">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<br/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlVersion" AutoPostBack="True" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVersion_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="158px" 
     DataSourceID="VersionDS" DataTextField="VERSION" 
     DataValueField="PROGRAM_ID"/>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="VersionDS" runat="server" 
     OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
     SelectMethod="GetData" 
     TypeName="WebAdminTools.DATA.DSTableAdapters.UpdateTA">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlProgram" DefaultValue="0" 
             Name="P_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I have `onSelectionIndexChanged` event handler for the second dropdownlist as well. When I try to pick item from second dropdownlist it resets to first one. I tried this [guide](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-filtering-with-two-dropdownlists-cs) What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

```
protected void ddlVersion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetCompaniesForUpdate();
}

private void GetCompaniesForUpdate()
{
    ProgramVersionTA ta = new ProgramVersionTA();
    var dt = new DS.ProgramsVersionsDataTable();
    ta.Fill(dt, Convert.ToInt32(ddlVersion.SelectedValue));
    var selectedVersion = Version.Parse(ddlVersion.SelectedValue);
    var companyForUpdate = dt.Where(c => Version.Parse(c.MAX_AVAILABLE_VERSION) > selectedVersion
                                         && Version.Parse(c.VERSION) < selectedVersion);
    lbCompanies.DataSource = companyForUpdate;
    lbCompanies.DataMember = "NAME";
    lbCompanies.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Show us `ddlVersion_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: I set a breakpoint there. It never fires.

Comment: I've solved this problem using Ajax controls toolkit cascading dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the postback. if u are setting a value to dropdownlist on form_load, please make sure that u put it inside the if(!Page.IsPostBack).

Comment: Did u set the autopostback to true? Regarding to the breakpoint that u put on the  selectedindexchange, it will not fires until u turned it on.

Comment: Did the page reload after u change the Dropdown2?

Comment: It looks like nothing happens. But if I try to navigate back the second dropdown set selected index to last item